# Paginação com sequelize + node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sequelize-js

Ola, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação node.js onde tenho que listar um cadastro de turmas. Porém como o numero de registros são muitos preciso fazer uma paginação, consegui isto fazendo uma função com os atributos offset e limit do sequelize conforme abaixo

Rotas:

```
router.get('/turmas/page/:skip', (req, res) => {
    Turma.select(req, res)
})
```

Função que busca os dados no banco

```
  select: (req, res) => {

        let page = 0;
        if (req.params) {

            page = parseInt(req.params.skip) * 3
        }

        console.log(page)

        Turma.findAll({
            limit: 3,
            offset: page
        }).then((turmas => {
            res.render('turma/index', {
                title: "Tumas",
                titlePanel: "Turmas",
                turmas: turmas
            })
        }))

    },
```

Porém queria saber se existe outra maneira de se fazer isso e como posso inserir isto no html do meu front-end sendo que ja criei a nav com as paginas conforme abaixo

```
<%- include ./../layout/header %>
<a href="/turmas/register">
   <button class="btn btn-success ">Nova turma</button>
</a>


 <div class="container">
     <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Serie</th>
            <th>Opções</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>



    <tbody>
  <% turmas.forEach((turma)=> { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= turma.TR_ID %></td>
            <td><%= turma.TR_NAME%></td>
            <td><%= turma.TR_YEAR %> Ano</td>
            <td>    

            <a href="turmas/update/<%= turma.TR_ID %>">
            <button class="btn btn-warning"> Editar </button>
            </a>

             <a href="turmas/delete/<%= turma.TR_ID %>">
                <button class="btn btn-danger"> Excluir </button>
             </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

         <% })%>


    </tbody>


</table>

        <!-- Nav com as paginas -->
        <nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Alguem saberia me dizer a melhor maneira para fazer está paginação com node.js + sequelize ? pode ser com outro exemplo de codigo.

Comment: Parece estar bem feito. Qual é o problema mesmo?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/35970/bruno-costa O back-end está funcionando o que gostaria de saber é como printar no front-end a nav para cada link de pagina. Ou seja como printar os botões para selecionar a pagina em questão e avançar.